# News Feed Web Part in the main landing page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

I need to add a news feed web part on the landing page of the SharePoint 2013 Site. I have activated the hidden feature 6928B0E5-5707-46a1-AE16-D6E52522D52B and can add the news feed web part. However I want the web part in the following fashion:

[image]

But I get the following following:

[image]

I have made the .ms-microfeed-microblogpart to display:none; in the css so cannot get the 'Share with everyone' and the blog part which I want. but what do I need to do to get the Newsfeed as shown in the top most pic.

Much Obliged